# Mapping an array within an object React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rest, ecmascript-6

I'm having a hard time with the map function. Here's what I did... I'm passing data as props from my parent component to child component. `{open, high, low, close, time }` are arrays which has EXACTLY 1,445 data sets so the content of each prop has pretty much a lot of data. I will be using the data of all 5 of these arrays so I stored them within the `conglomerate` object.

Please move your attention to `const chartRender` As you can see I'm not doing something right. Since i stored `{open, high, low, close, and time}` within the conglomerate object, when I execute the .map method it only renders 5 arrays, maybe because because there are 5 arrays within the `conglomerate` array.

```
function QuoteChart(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { open, high, low, close, time } = props;
    const conglomerate = [open, high, low, close, time];
    console.log(conglomerate);

    const chartRender = conglomerate.map((options) => ({
        x: new Date(options[4]),
        y: [options[3], options[1], options[2], options[0]],
    }));
    console.log(chartRender)};
```

The goal is to store the data within `conglomerate` then map the 1,445 data sets within each array in `{open, high, low, close, time}` to the map function

Additional context: Here is what shows up when I `console.log(conglomerate)` I'd like to assign each array within the `conglomerate` object into the `chartRender` function.[image: ArrayOriginal]

Instead this is what shows up when I `console.log(chartRender)` as you can see, something is broken. I'd really love it if you guys could help me out.

[image: ArrayGarbage]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what behavior you want. `conglomerate.map` will return an array. What do you wan that array to be?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what data you're trying to get with your map function. Since you're just placing 5 arrays inside a larger one, you have an array with 5 arrays as elements.  The ```options``` argument in your map function refers to one of the child arrays as it maps over them.

Comment: Since conglomerate contains the individual elements of the arrays I need. I'd want to create a map function and assign each of those smaller arrays in the map function. Basically let's say within conglomerate I want to map the "open" array stored in options[0] then how would I go about that l? Also after that I'd want to map the "close" array stored in options[1] etc. Effectively I need to access the smaller arrays in the big one since I need their data for the map function

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning to concatenate the arrays stored in `conglomerate` and operate on them before returning them to `chartRender`, this should help.

```js
const chartRender = conglomerate.reduce((accumulator, nestedArray) => {
  // do some operation on nestedArray
  const newArray = nestedArray.map(value => ({ x: value, y: value/2 }))
  accumulator = accumulator.concat(newArray);
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep them separate you can just use map twice:

```
conglomerate.map((array)=>{  //this iterates through the 5 arrays in conglomerate
  return array.map((options)=>{ //this iterates through the data in the arrays
    return {
      x: new Date(options),
      y: [options, options[1], options[2], options[0]],
    }
  })
 })
```

If you don't need to keep them separate and want just 1 big array with all the data you can just concatenate them at the beginning and then map:

```
const conglomerate = [...open, ...high, ...low, ...close, ...time];
```

Comment: ahhh, i  see. I think there's a misunderstanding. there's a reason why I formatted the output of the array to `x: new Date(options[4]),  y: [options[3], options[1], options[2], options[0]]` I need to render that specific format of data for a chart. I would call `chartRender` in `const config = { series: [ {data: [chartRender]}]}` Hopefully, what would happen is I'd call chartRender and it would map through the data given. I'm doing this for a chart and the format needs to be `x: new Date(options[4]), y: [options[3], options[1], options[2], options[0]]` for the dataset